# How to execute a Git-Lab pipeline job conditionally with OR relation between different keys for the "only" parameter

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

While there are many questions and answers around conditional job execution of GitLab CI pipelines I could not find a solution for my problem: To trigger a particular job from pipeline when there are changes in some files **OR** a env variable is set to a specific value. Something like this:

```
job_build:

  tags:
    - executor-shell

  stage:
    build

  script:
    - ./gitlab_ci_helper.sh build

  only:
    changes:
      - /path/to/files/with/changes/*
    variables:
      - $BUILD_IS_A_MUST == "TRUE"
```

As per the [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#onlyexcept-advanced) from GitLab itself, we have the following:
[image]

Now the question I have is how to make the condition `NOT(any of variables) AND (any of changes))` which is same as `(any of variables) OR (any of changes)` but applied for the `only` parameter?

Answer (score 2):

Well, in the end, looks like found myself the answer to the question. It turns out that starting from GitLab version 12.3 a new configuration parameter was introduced called [`rules:`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rules)

Looks like this parameter is exactly addressing the problem I was looking for an answer. While I don't have yet GitLab 12.3 version to test it, the above ci job would be changed into something like this:

```
job_build:

  tags:
    - executor-shell

  stage:
    build

  script:
    - ./gitlab_ci_helper.sh build

  rules:
    - changes:
      - /path/to/files/with/changes/*
      when: on_success
    - if: $BUILD_IS_A_MUST == "TRUE"
      when: on_success
```

In this case, the default rule will get resolved to `when: never` which is what I'm after thus no need to specify it.

Comment: Just to confirm that above was tested as well and it does work as expected.